# Get lowest per date from multiple arrays in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I've the following structure of docs:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5786458371d24d924d8b4575"),
    "uniqueNumber" : "3899822714",
    "lastUpdatedAt" : ISODate("2016-07-13T20:11:11.000Z"),
    "new" : [ 
        {
            "price" : 8.4,
            "created" : ISODate("2016-07-13T13:11:28.000Z")
        }, 
        {
            "price" : 10.0,
            "created" : ISODate("2016-07-13T14:50:56.000Z")
        }
    ],
    "used" : [ 
        {
            "price" : 10.99,
            "created" : ISODate("2016-07-08T13:46:31.000Z")
        }, 
        {
            "price" : 8.59,
            "created" : ISODate("2016-07-13T13:11:28.000Z")
        }
    ]
}
```

Now I need to get a list that gives me the lowest price of each array per date.

So, as example:

```
{ 
    "uniqueNumber" : 1234,
    "prices" : {
        "created" : 2016-07-08,
        "minNew" : 123,
        "minUsed" : 22
    }
}
```

By now I've built the following query

```
db.getCollection('col').aggregate([
    {
        $match : {
            "uniqueNumber" : "3899822714"
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind : "$used"
    },
    {
        $project : {
            "uniqueNumber" : "$uniqueNumber",
            "price" : "$used.price",
            "ts" : "$used.created"
        } 
    },
    {
        $sort : { "ts" : 1 }
    },
    {
        $group : {_id: "$uniqueNumber", priceOfMaxTS : { $min: "$price" }, ts : { $last: "$ts" }}
    }
]);
```

But this one will only give me the lowest price for the highest date. I couldn't really find anything that pushes me to the right direction to get the desired result.

**UPDATE**

I've found a way to get the lowest price of the `used` array grouped by day with this query:

```
db.getCollection('col').aggregate([
    {
        $match : {
            "uniqueNumber" : "3899822714"
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind : "$used"
    },
    {
        $project : {
            "asin" : "$uniqueNumber",
            "price" : "$used.price",
            "ts" : "$used.created",
            "y" : { "$year" : "$used.created" },
            "m" : { "$month" : "$used.created" },
            "d" : { "$dayOfMonth" : "$used.created" }
        } 
    },
    {
        $group : { _id : { "year" : "$y", "month" : "$m", "day" : "$d" }, minPriceOfDay : { $min: "$price" }}
    }
]);
```

No I only need to find a way to do this also to the `new` array in the same query.

Comment: Where is the array field in your document? why do you have dynamic fields' name in your document? It will not make your life any easier.

Comment: @SSDMS Edited the Doc in the question to display the valid JSON, sorry on that. `new` and `used` are both arrays. What do you mean by dynamic name fields? That the keys of the array aren't named?

Comment: What is your MongoDB version?

Comment: @SSDMS The version of my local and the productive machine is 2.6

Comment: Do you want the lowest price of each array per date for each document?

Comment: Yes! But there's only one document per uniqueNumber per Design.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117380/discussion-between-ssdms-and-khorneholy).